# How can I get file from input in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, input, internet-explorer-8, fileapi

How I can get file in IE(8) like this:

```
<input id="files" type="file">

<script>
    var file = this.files[0]; //(FF, Chrome)
</script>
```

for uploading?

Comment: What would this mean? "Get file" is a little vague, and I'm not sure what `[0]` could mean here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.
IE8 doesn't support this feature.

Comment: Welcome to the painful world of IE development.

Comment: Oh :) Can you recommend any way for upoading from IE via JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Native file input boxes do not have the `files` attribute in IE8.
However when the user selects a file its URL becomes the `value` of the input element, so there is no problem to retrieve it.

Comment: That's not quite correct, insofar as the value will always contain "C:\fakepath\RealLeafFilename". This helps prevent information disclosure of the local filesystem.